# Why do files and folders extracted with WinRAR from command line have %20 instead of space in name?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, rar, winrar

I'm trying to extract a ZIP file using a script that calls WinRAR, but folders with a space in the name are being unzipped as `My%20Folder`. Any ideas?

```
set rar="%home%\Automation\winrar.exe"
%rar% x "%nugetfileweb%" *.* "%releasefrombuildserver%\web\"
```

Comment: zip and rar won't rename files like that. They have NO reason to url-encode spaces in filenames. most likely the original zip was created with the %20 in place already.

Comment: Hi, thank. Im looking at the original nuget package and there is no url encoding. Im not saying you're wrong though/ There is much more to this script that may be doing this. Ill pass your info on to my colleague

Comment: Please add the output of `%rar% t archive.rar` to your question.

Comment: Ive just come across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269743/winrar-command-line-replacing-space-with-20?noredirect=1#comment30237274_20269743, this describes how to use nuget to publish the files, which would be preferred. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Whether **WinRAR** nor any other compression tool creating RAR or ZIP archives or extracting RAR / ZIP archives uses [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) respectively [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Files and folders with `%20` in name instead of space character after extraction were added to the archive already with `%20` in file / folder name.

So nothing can be done during extraction to replace each `%20` by space in all file / folder names.

Here is a batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem The start folder can be specified as argument of the batch file.
rem The current working directory is used as start folder if batch
rem file is executed without any argument.
set "StartFolder=%~1"
if "%StartFolder%"=="" set "StartFolder=%CD%" else (
  rem Remove backslash from end of passed start folder path if present.
  rem That would not be really necessary but makes output looking better.
  if "%StartFolder:~-1%"=="\" set "StartFolder=%StartFolder:~0,-1%"
)
echo.
echo Searching for files with %%20 in name to replace by space in all folders
echo starting from "%StartFolder%" ...
echo.

set ExitCode=0
set FoundCounter=0
set RenameCounter=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%F in (`dir "%StartFolder%\*%%20*" /A-D /B /S 2^> nul`) do (
    set "EncodedName=%%~nxF"
    set "DecodedName=!EncodedName:%%20= !"
    set /A FoundCounter+=1
    ren "%%F" "!DecodedName!" 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
       echo Error: Failed to rename file "%%F"
    ) else (
       echo File "!EncodedName!" renamed to "!DecodedName!"
       set /A RenameCounter+=1
    )
)
if not "!FoundCounter!"=="!RenameCounter!" set ExitCode=1

echo.
if "!FoundCounter!"=="0" (
   echo No file found with %%20 in name.
) else if "!RenameCounter!"=="1" (
   if "!FoundCounter!"=="1" (
      echo Renamed 1 file successfully.
   ) else (
      echo Renamed 1 of !FoundCounter! files successfully.
   )
) else (
   echo Renamed !RenameCounter! of !FoundCounter! files successfully.
)
echo.
echo Searching for folders with %%20 in name to replace by space in all folders
echo starting from "%StartFolder%" ...
echo.

set LoopRun=0
set FoundCounter=0
set RenameCounter=0

rem It is necessary to run the following loop more than once if
rem a folder with %20 in name contains in folder tree a subfolder
rem also with %20 in name. The loop is executed 20 times at most.
:NextRun
set RenameError=no
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`dir "%StartFolder%\*%%20*" /AD /B /S 2^> nul`) do (
    set "EncodedName=%%~nxD"
    set "DecodedName=!EncodedName:%%20= !"
    ren "%%D" "!DecodedName!" 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
       set RenameError=yes
       if "!LoopRun!"=="20" (
          echo Error: Failed to rename folder "%%D"
          set /A FoundCounter+=1
       )
    ) else (
       echo Folder "!EncodedName!" renamed to "!DecodedName!"
       set /A RenameCounter+=1
       set /A FoundCounter+=1
    )
)

if "!RenameError!"=="yes" (
   set /A LoopRun+=1
   if not "!LoopRun!"=="21" goto NextRun
)
if not "!FoundCounter!"=="!RenameCounter!" set /A ExitCode+=2

echo.
if "!FoundCounter!"=="0" (
   echo No folder found with %%20 in name.
) else if "!RenameCounter!"=="1" (
   if "!FoundCounter!"=="1" (
      echo Renamed 1 folder successfully.
   ) else (
      echo Renamed 1 of !FoundCounter! folders successfully.
   )
) else (
   echo Renamed !RenameCounter! of !FoundCounter! folders successfully.
)
echo.
pause

if "!ExitCode!"=="1" (
   endlocal
   rem At least 1 file could not be renamed.
   exit /B 1
) else if "!ExitCode!"=="2" (
   endlocal
   rem At least 1 folder could not be renamed.
   exit /B 2
) else if "!ExitCode!"=="3" (
   endlocal
   rem At least 1 file and 1 folder could not be renamed.
   exit /B 3
) else (
   endlocal
   rem Success as no file / folder to rename found or all renamed.
   exit /B 0
)
```

For example folder `C:\Temp` contains following folders and files:

- **My%20Folder**

  - **Sub%20Folder**

    - One%20More%20File.txt
    - Text_File.txt
  - Another%20File.txt
  - File%201.txt
  - File2.txt

Above batch file outputs on running it with `C:\Temp` as argument:

```
Searching for files with %20 in name to replace by space in all folders
starting from "C:\Temp" ...

File "Another%20File.txt" renamed to "Another File.txt"
File "File%201.txt" renamed to "File 1.txt"
File "One%20More%20File.txt" renamed to "One More File.txt"

Renamed 3 of 3 files successfully.

Searching for folders with %20 in name to replace by space in all folders
starting from "C:\Temp" ...

Folder "My%20Folder" renamed to "My Folder"
Folder "Sub%20Folder" renamed to "Sub Folder"

Renamed 2 of 2 folders successfully.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

And folder `C:\Temp` contains after batch execution:

- **My Folder**

  - **Sub Folder**

    - One More File.txt
    - Text_File.txt
  - Another File.txt
  - File 1.txt
  - File2.txt

The batch file can be called from another batch file. It has 4 exit codes (errorlevels) whereby the batch file exits with value **0** on success. For details on return values see the code lines at bottom of the batch file code.